# java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.kalugaguide.Item

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(context: Context, vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)?.run {
        setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        draw(canvas)
        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(10.0f)
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f)
    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        val success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.mapstyle))
        if (!success) {
            Log.e("MapsActivity", "Style parsing failed.")
        }
    } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
        Log.e("MapsActivity", "Can't find style. Error: ", e)
    }
    val item= intent.extras?.get("item") as Item
    val width=item.width
    val MuzeumOFCosmos = LatLng(width,36.23063585608777)
    val zoomLevel = 14.3f
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MuzeumOFCosmos, zoomLevel))
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(MuzeumOFCosmos).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(baseContext, R.drawable.drw)))
}
```

}

I want to get data from the main activity (coordinates) to the map activity,but I get this error, I was told that the problem is in the string intent.extras?.get ("item") that I have it equal to null

Comment: This means the bundle doesn't contain your item with the key "item", so it returns a null value, which you can't cast to a non-nullable Item. Check your code that launches this Activity to be sure you've attached it to the Intent.

Comment: I reviewed all the code and found nothing , but I decided to check and Double data with toString is output, and in Google maps it gives this error

Comment: I tried to do so: val item = intent.extras?.get("item") as Item?
        val width= item?.width
        val MuzeumOFCosmos = LatLng(width!!,36.23063585608777) , but again it gave an error : java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kalugaguide.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.kt:57)

Comment: The `?.` allows you to call functions and properties of something that is nullable (maybe null). `!!` declares "this thing that is maybe null is definitely not null and you should crash with a NullPointerException if it is because I'm so sure that it isn't". The source of your problem is that you have not passed an Item in the bundle of the Intent that launched this Activity.

Comment: Please provide the code of `Item` and `MainActivity`, without them it's quite difficult to determine the cause of the error.